# Mount exFat drive on Ubuntu not as root

Tags: automount, exfat

I realised that Ubuntu automatically mounts my internal drives which are some exFats automatically when I try to open them. Thats good.

However, it is mounted as "root" and I want to mount it as my current user. Is there any way to make it mount not as root through some configurations or do I have to do it as a command?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

### Software to run exFAT

Depending on the version of Ubuntu or Ubuntu based operating system you may or may not need to install the following program packages,

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
```

See this link for more details,

[How do I copy a file larger than 4GB to a USB flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706)

### Mounting exFAT

Many versions of Ubuntu and Ubuntu based operating systems will mount Microsoft file systems (FAT32, exFAT, NTFS) with read/write permissions automatically for root as well as the current user.

But some versions (of Ubuntu and Ubuntu based operating systems) will mount them with write permissions only for root (or not at all). Then you can unmount and remount (mount) the file system with commands like this,

**Create mountpoint** (only if you want a new mountpoint)

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sd1
```

**Unmount** (only if already mounted)

```
sudo umount /dev/sdxn   # general syntax
sudo umount /dev/sdb1   # modify to match your case
```

**Check your userID's `uid` number** (it is usually 1000, sometimes 1001 or 1002 ...)

```
grep ^"$USER" /etc/group
```

and use that number if you want to grab ownership (default is `root`).

***Example of mount command line*** that should give you something that is close to what you want,

```
sudo mount -o rw,users,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117 /dev/sdxn /mnt/sd1  # general syntax
sudo mount -o rw,users,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sd1  # modify to match your case
```

See this link for more details,

[How to change default permissions on automounted usb flash, formatted in NTFS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956002/how-to-change-default-permissions-on-automounted-usb-flash-formatted-in-ntfs/956024#956024)

Comment: But how to mount automatically when pluged in or after boot?

Comment: @Felipe, You can add a line in `/etc/fstab` with the relevant mount options for the partition with the exFAT file system. You find advice at `man fstab` - The mount options should be in the fourth field of that line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the default automount behaviour which is provided by gnome features does not have so much possibility for configuration.

What you want to do, is you add mount option `umask=0`, which can be done if configured in /etc/fstab like this:

```
/dev/sda1 /media/usbdrive exfat rw,async,umask=0 0 0
```

This kind of goes against the automount concept though, since it means static configuration.

It could probably be achivied by using automount and autofs though:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs

If you chose this path, then you should disable the automount option in gnome:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Configuring_Automounting

Comment: I don't have a `/etc/fstab` file (Ubuntu 14.10).

Answer (score 0):

### Execute Rights, Least Access & Automount

In addition to the other answers, after you have checked your uid, drive uuid, and made your mountpoint folder—but **if you also want your user to have execute rights on the drive** to run scripts or applications stored on the drive **and you would like to restrict access to only your user**, usually for servers or computers that grant ssh access, or have other user services running, or plainly for general security and least access—then you should modify the mount as:

```
sudo mount -o rw,exec,uid=1000,umask=007 /dev/sdxn /mnt/sd1
```

with your uid, /dev/ and /mnt/mountfolder .

'rw' for read/write; 'exec' for execute rights; and 'dmask=007,fmask=007' is synonymous with 'umask=007', which un-masks the rw+exec rights from 'all' users for directories and files, but allows the permissions for owner (the uid) and group (should always end up being root)

### Automount exFat accessible for one User+Root rwx access

sudo-edit your /etc/fstab. You can confirm the location of the fstab file with

```
man fstab #look under "Synopsis"
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

And add a line with the automount instructions of format

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options>                        <dump>  <pass>
UUID=FDB9-7531  /mnt/mydrive  exfat  rw,exec,auto,uid=1000,umask=007  0       0
```

.. with your own UUID, mount folder, and uid as @sudodus detailed. 'auto' is added here so you can immediately test the automount without rebooting:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo mount -a
```