# How to change default permissions on automounted usb flash, formatted in NTFS?

Tags: usb, permissions, ntfs, automount

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my computer with XFCE as Desktop environment. When i'm inserting usb flash formatted in NTFS system mounts it with default permissions on files are setted in 600, and I want to change this behaviour to mount with default permissions 660 instead. How can I do it?

Comment: Unless you're using the same USB drive again and again, in which case you should set up `/etc/fstab` mount using options inhttps://askubuntu.com/a/11843/158442, plus the option `nofail`.

Comment: Sounds sad. So it seems not possible to implement such behaviour for any mounted flash.

Comment: It is possible, at least something very close to what you want, with command lines in a terminal window. I will write an answer to explain.

Comment: @muru, The OP, razamanaza, seems to be happy with my answer. Would it be meaningful to edit this question, for example to remove  'default permissions' and 'automounting', and after that reopen this question? -- I think that otherwise people will not notice it (and not be helped, but instead learn that this is impossible due to the link to the 'original question'). -- Or should I move my answer to the 'original question' of the link or to another and better 'original question'?

Comment: @sudodus why bother? It's not like your answer is going to be deleted, or this post will be hidden from search results. Besides, the generic solution to mount NTFS partitions with some mode is given in the other post to I linked to, so either way, it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

### Mount NTFS partition in a USB drive with custom permissions and owner

*Assumption: the USB drive is seen as* **`sdb1`**, *modify to match the drive letter and partition number in your case*. The general syntax is **`sdxn`**, where **`x`** is the drive letter and **`n`** is the partition number as seen by for example `sudo lsblk -f`

You can use the following command line method in order to get other permissions and ownership than the default.

**Create mountpoint** (only if you want a new mountpoint)

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sd1
```

**Unmount** (only if already mounted)

```
sudo umount /dev/sdxn   # general syntax
sudo umount /dev/sdb1   # modify to match your case
```

**Check your userID's `uid` number** (it is usually 1000, sometimes 1001 or 1002 ...)

```
grep ^"$USER" /etc/group
```

and use that number if you want to grab ownership (default is `root`).

***Example of mount command line*** that should give you something that is close to what you want,

```
sudo mount -o rw,users,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117 /dev/sdxn /mnt/sd1  # general syntax
sudo mount -o rw,users,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sd1  # modify to match your case
```

**Example with full permissions for everybody** (convenient, but not safe, when there are several users),

```
sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=000 /dev/sdxn /mnt/sd1  # general
sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=000 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sd1  # modify to match your case
```

**Check permissions and owner** of the directories and files

```
ls -ld /mnt/sd1
ls -ld /mnt/sd1/*
```

**Test**

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'Hello World' > /mnt/sd1/hello.txt"  # test writing with sudo
cat /mnt/sd1/hello.txt                   # test reading (as user)
ls -l /mnt/sd1                           # check permissions of the content
rm /mnt/sd1/hello.txt                    # test removing (as user)
echo 'I am a user' > /mnt/sd1/user.txt   # test writing (as user)
```

### If this does not work

If this does not work, you may find a solution or at least an explanation at the following link,

[Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted: Analysis of the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)