# Can't copy paste or mkdir in a partition without root permission after creating it with gparted

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, nautilus, gparted

This was the photo of my gparted from hdd:

[image: PIC 1]

I  wanted to increase the hdd space by unmounting and deleting the extended partition sdb1,then creating a new partition...

Now in gparted,I have this:

[image: PIC 2]

So i wanted to open the hdd from nautilus,but i couldn't open that...

I faced with an error which says:

> **This location could not be displayed**
>
> You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "lost+found".

Now,What should i do?
I can do nothing from nautilus(copy paste a file or folder or open a new folder in hdd),but i can do anything from terminal with root permission.

Check this:
[image: PIC 3]

[image: PIC 4]

Comment: The contents of your new partition are displayed already, only one single folder exists in your partition, this is the folder `lost+found`. This folder is created automatically by the system, is owned by root and all other users do not have any permissions (and we mostly don't need to access this folder). This folder is not your partition, it is a folder in your partition.

Comment: If you press Ctrl+H to show hidden files in Nautilus you may see a second folder called `.Trash-1000` or similar. This folder is also created by default.

Comment: @mook765 so what should i do? how can i create 1TB free space and use that partition??

Comment: You should be able to use the partition just right now. Try to open a second Nautilus window and drag a file or folder from your home-folder to free space near the `lost+found`-folder-icon in the other Nautilus-window. Does that work?

Comment: unfortunately...cant copy and paste any files in free space... the free space is hdd...it's not /home or /var /tmp or anything like that... it's a internal free hdd... my OS is on ssd @mook765

Comment: Your screen shot shows a 931 GB partition mounted to your file-system, the Nautilus window shows the content of this partition. Just right now your fresh and correctly created partition contains only the two folders I mentioned in my comments above. Everything just looks correct.

Comment: But it's formatted ext4. By default it's owned by root. `sudo chown user.group /path/to/mount/point` should fix this.

Comment: @vidarlo chown: invalid user: ‘user.group’

Comment: @sina - replace user and group with your username and groupname, e.g. chown sina.sina ...

Comment: sudo chown msi.msi /media/msi/c0d44499-6cbe-44da-92da-f1a48159e079/sina
  thank u it work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one or more directories in your partition using

```
sudo mkdir directory-name
```

and change the ownershíp to your regular user ID using

```
sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" directory-name
```

Then you should be able to use the directories (in my example "directory-name") as your regular user. In these directories you will be able to create and delete subdirectories and files without restrictions.

---

Note for other users: Please notice that this is a linux **`ext4`** file system. If you have a Microsoft file system, FAT32, exFAT or NTFS, the permissions and ownership for linux is set when mounting the file system. The  permissions and ownership will be inherited by all subdirectories and files. If the automatic mounting does not provide write access you can try according to the following link,

[How to change default permissions on automounted usb flash, formatted in NTFS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956002/how-to-change-default-permissions-on-automounted-usb-flash-formatted-in-ntfs/956024#956024)

Comment: Or simply chown the root of that partition to user.

Comment: @vidarlo, Yes, you are right, but I think it is a good idea to let the root of a partition be owned by the root user, and have partitions owned by other user IDs. Both ways work :-)

Comment: sudo mkdir sina ............ sudo chown "$USER" "$USER" sina .....chown: cannot access 'msi': No such file or directory

Comment: @sudodus please check the edited question

Comment: Sorry for the typing error: there should be a colon between the user entry and group entry, so `sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" directory-name`

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

You will find list of partitions, so you can identify the partition in which you are not able to copy paste or make new folder.

Run second command

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb3
```

Replace `/dev/sdb3` by your drive

Now run third command

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/dravinash/General/
```

Replace `/media/dravinash/General/` by your drive name

Now restart the system.

I am not an expert but I found these commands on web and it worked for me.....