# How to Mount NTFS partition in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, ntfs-3g

I'm new to Ubuntu. Installed ubuntu by formatting my existing C Drive in Windows 10 OS. So I have only Ubuntu in my laptop. My D drive is left untouched which is a NTFS file system. Please guide me how to mount this so that I can work with my files.

Comment: Open `Files` (nautilus) and on the left side below *network* you can see all the partitions. Click on them to mount them.

Comment: @jdwolf please only comment if you want to ask for clarification from the author or suggest how they can improve their question etc. Comments to express your opinion on a post are not useful. See "When should I comment" in the relevant [help center page](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The following link may help you, https://askubuntu.com/questions/956002/how-to-change-default-permissions-on-automounted-usb-flash-formatted-in-ntfs/956024#956024

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I apologize, I should have tried something before posting a question here. I read through some articles on this and I wasn't sure to try one, because I don't want to lose my files since I do not have a back up. Now with your instructions I'm able to successfully map it. Once again, thank you very much. :)

Comment: you should search and try before posting "how to"... next time

Comment: Sure, will do..

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad it works for you and thanks for letting us know :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

Answer (score 43):

Do you want to mount it once or auto mount it?
For mounting it once:

1.First create a directory where u want to mount it.

`sudo mkdir /media/windows`

2. Now you have to find which partition is the NTFS one by using:

   `sudo fdisk -l`
3. If your NTFS partition is for example `/dev/sdb1` to mount it use:

   `sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sdb1 /media/windows`
4. To unmount simply do:

   `sudo umount /media/windows`

If you want to auto mount it check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions).

Comment: maybe as an alternative, I used `apt install ntfs-3g` and `sudo mount -t auto /dev/sdb1 /media/your_favorite_path/`

Comment: Worth clarifying that the answer will mount as read-only while the comment above will mount as read+write

Answer (score 0):

Check what you have in your /dev/ directory by typing in terminal:

```
ls /dev/sd*
```

If you have only one hard drive, you could see there devices like sda2, sda5. You could create directory as AsenM suggested and mount by hand every time you need it.
To avoid manual mounting you could add similar to the next string in your /etc/fstab file:

```
/dev/sda5 /mnt/super ntfs-3g permissions,users,auto,locale=en_US.utf8 0 2
```

And also, in some cases you could encounter problems with read/write mounting if you did not have Full access for Everyone from Windows. In this case you could make bootable flash drive with windows, boot it and grant all permissions for user Everyone for the whole drive.
I've encountered this problem recently. What is strange, the error message was saying that my disk is in hibernation state. So it could be mounted only with read only access.

Answer (score 0):

I found another alternative easy solution for NTFS formatted usb keys in ubuntu/linux.

1. Plug in the usb
2. Open "Disks" application on Ubuntu.
3. Click the icon representing the USB.
4. Click the Icon of mounting (like a play Icon)

Done. Now check on File explorer, you will see also listed on the left the new mounted usb-key's location