# One of my partitions doesn't mount

Tags: partitioning, mount

just upgraded to 18.04 and installed alongside win10, I followed a guide to do so. I must admit when it said where to mount the partition used for storage I was dubious, but did it anyway.

It said to mount it /home/storage. It appears when I use lsblk, but I can't figure out how to mount it.

Here is my lsblk output, the drive in question is sda.

```
 NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
loop1    7:1    0 140.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop2    7:2    0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop3    7:3    0  34.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop4    7:4    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/117
loop5    7:5    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop6    7:6    0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/40
loop7    7:7    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop8    7:8    0   4.9M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/42
loop9    7:9    0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop10   7:10   0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/199
loop11   7:11   0    87M  1 loop /snap/core/5145
loop12   7:12   0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/103
sda      8:0    1 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    1  14.7G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    1 147.1G  0 part /home
└─sda3   8:3    1 304.1G  0 part /home/storage
sdb      8:16   1 117.4G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   450M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   1   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb3   8:19   1    16M  0 part 
└─sdb4   8:20   1 116.8G  0 part /media/scott/AACE28D1CE289819
sdc      8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0   1.8T  0 part /media/scott/Seagate Expansion Drive
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sda is the entire hard drive. sda3 is already mounted at /home/storage

Comment: I thought so, however I can't access it.

Comment: Perhaps start a new question with more details

Comment: I'm not sure what else is needed, what would you suggest?

Comment: Why do you say you don't have access?  What file system on the partition?

Comment: It's ntfs, as wanted to be able to share it with windows. It doesn't show up as a mounted drive on the desktop or in any folders.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/978746/how-to-mount-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu-16-04 .you also have to turn off fast boot in windows

Comment: Yeah I did that once I installed Windows. I can boot into Ubuntu no problem, it just doesn't give me access to the ntfs partition.