# Dual Boot (windows 8.1 and Ubuntu)

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I am using a dual boot system, while using Ubuntu I want to access windows folders, data, etc.
is it possible? how?

Comment: There is a recipe in https://askubuntu.com/questions/978746/how-to-mount-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

no need to do anything.
in dual boot systems Ubuntu(or any other Linux) has access to Windows directories but you can't access Linux directories from windows.
[image]